# Login form fails to login client

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I've been trying to create an admin panel for my website. I created a login form but whenever I try to log in, it says that the user does not exist. I can't seem to find where I made a mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login - Admin panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
include 'db.php'; 
      ?>
     <?php 
     include 'functions.php';
     ?>
<?php
include 'title_bar.php';
?>
<h3>Login Here: </h3>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $password = $_POST['password']; 
 if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
   echo "<p>Fields should not be empty</p>";
 } else {
   $check_login=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, type FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_login) == 1){
      $run=mysqli_fetch_array($check_login);
      $user_id=$run['id'];
      $type=$run['type'];
        if($type =='d') {
          echo "<p>Your acount is deactivated by an admin!</p>";
        } else {
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
          header('location: adminpanel.php');
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Wrong Username or Password</p>";
    }
  }
}
?>
<form method='post'>
User name: 
<input type ='text' name = 'username' />
<br/><br/>
Password:
<input type = 'password' name = 'password' />
<br/><br/>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value='Login' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the user exist in your DB? Do your gaggle of `if` statements actually evaluate the way you think they do? Is `mysqli_num_rows()` only returning 1 row? Have you tried the SQL manually to see if it returns what you think it does?  Are `$_POST` values set correctly?You have to do this basic debugging work yourself.

Comment: It does exist, yes

Comment: `session_start()`, where is that?

Comment: `header('location: adminpanel.php');` will probably not work. Needs to be placed before output to the browser. Also should have `exit;` directly after.

Comment: Don't put raw user input into your query: `"SELECT id, type FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"`. Needs to be parameterized with a  bind.

Comment: Don't store plaintext passwords in your database. Use `password_hash()` & `password_verify()` or compatible library to store password hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I see this all the time on SO, I will address some of my comments. There are a lot of reasons why it could fail based on what you have. First off, a solid framework would do almost all this for you, you would just have to do basic logic but not all the grunt work. Second, just because you want to echo some text in a specific part of your page, doesn't mean you should do a bunch of logic that leads up to `echo` in the same part of the page. The idea is that the browser output is the last thing to happen so you will want to do the bulk of your logic before the page outputs.

First break up your logic into a specific-task functions/class/methods that will be easily understood and ready to be re-used:

**/functions.php**

```
<?php
// I am going to use PDO because I am more familiar with it
function verifyUser($username,$password,$con)
    {
        // Get the basics from the database
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT `password`,`type`,`id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :0");
        // Bind the value for security
        $query->execute(array(":0"=>$username));
        // Get the results
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // If empty, return false
        if(!$result)
            return array('verified'=>false);
        // You need to store the password using password_hash()
        $verified = password_verify($password,$result['password']);
        // If user is revoked
        $revoked = is_deactivated($result);
        // Return all the validation settings
        return array(
            'type'=>$result['type'],
            'id'=>$result['id'],
            'revoked'=> $revoked,
            'verified'=>$verified,
            'valid'=>($verified && !$revoked)
        );
    }

function getUserById($id,$con)
    {
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :0");
        $query->execute(array(":0"=>$id));
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!$result)
            return false;

        return $result;
    }

function is_deactivated($userArr = false,$con = false)
    {
        // Set default user empty
        $user = false;
        // If value is numeric (id)
        if(is_numeric($userArr)) {
            // Get the data by from database, assign to user
            $user = getUserById($userArr,$con);
        }
        // If the value is an array, just assign to user
        elseif(is_array($userArr))
            $user = userArr;
        // If the value is still empty, stop, return deactivated
        if(empty($user))
            return true;
        else
           // If user is valid (in db), return bool if they are revoked
           return ($user['type'] == 'd');
    }

function loginObserver(&$error,$con)
    {
        // See if the action to log in is set
        if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login') {
            // Run the verify function
            $verify = verifyUser($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$con);
            // If user is in db
            if($verify['verified']) {
                // See if they are revoked, send back error
                if($verify['revoked']) {
                    $error = 'revoked';
                    return false;
                }
                // Assign your session id
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $verify['id'];
                // Return true for success
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // User was not in system, send invalid error
                $error = 'invalid';
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
            // Return a string so the subsequent logic knows that
            // no attempt was made to log in.
            return 'invalid';
    }
```

Secondly, now that you have all your business logic stored away in contained functions (classes/methods) you can cleanly apply them to the page.

**/login.php**

```
<?php
// Put this at the very beginning. I would consider putting it on a config page and 
// including it would be better because then you will  have some consistency 
// through your site
session_start();
// Add your functions and or classes, better yet would be to have an autoloader
// to load classes and a pseudo-autoloader to load functions
include('functions.php');
// Put your database connection at the top, on the config page would be better
include('db.php');
// Move logic to the top and pass errors to the page
$error = false;
// Run the observer function
$login = loginObserver($error,$con);
// Invalid means no attempt was made to login
if($login != 'invalid')
    // If there are no errors (empty), redirect
    if(!$error) {
        // This needs to go before output of html to browser
        header('location: adminpanel.php');
        // Stops the script from processing the rest of the page
        exit;
    }
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login - Admin panel</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// This is probably fine, it's likely just html
include('title_bar.php');
?>
<h3>Login Here: </h3>
<?php if($error) {
    echo ($error == 'invalid')? 'Wrong username or password.':'Your access has been revoked by admin.';
} ?>
    <form method='post'>
        <!-- add an action here -->
        <!-- You should do a token system for verifying submission authenticity -->
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
        User name: 
        <input type='text' name='username' />
        <br/><br/>
        Password:
        <input type='password' name='password' />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, this code is not tested so there may be errors in logic. It is intended to show you how to apply my (and perhaps other's comments practically). I don't want to say "Don't do this and don't do that" but don't show an alternative. *This script is based on yours so you can identify similarities easier, but is no way implied this is the only way, or the correct way to do a login.*